# UITableViewCell didselectrow event delay

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i am subclassing `UITableViewCell` in my `UITableView`. i did it about a thousand times before but now i am trying to catch this delegate event :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

when the cell is touched this callback should be invoked.
but i invoked only if i am pressing like 6 seconds or 6 times after the touch, but not every touch.

the tableview is a subview of a subclassed `UIView` and i call this in the `awakeFromNib` :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
_table_view.delegate = self;
_table_view.dataSource = self;
}
```

the tableview draws itself just fine but this event is not working well.
any ideas?

here is the `UITableViewCell` subclass code .m

```
#import "FLBlockedPersonCell.h"

@implementation FLBlockedPersonCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
}



@end
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you add UITapGestureRecognizer on your view, when you touched it, the UITapGestureRecognizer first response.

Comment: that will be the sulotion if i want figure this out.

Comment: If you do have a UITapGestureRecognizer on the view, set recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

When the cell is touched this invoke should happen:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
```

The didSelect invokes only if you really selected a cell, not just tapped it. Also several methods like shouldHighlight and willSelect will invoke upon touch.

Comment: it happens only when the cell is highlighted after 1 second of press i need it to happen when i touch the cell

Comment: what about shoudlHighlight?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure the `tableView.allowsSelection` is set to `YES`.

Sounds to me that the `UIView` which the `UITableView` is a subview of is blocking the touch events.

You need to make sure that the `UIView` subclass is not capturing any of the touch events. I would remove any of these methods from your `UIView` subclass:

```
touchesBegan:withEvent: 
touchesMoved:withEvent: 
touchesEnded:withEvent: 
touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

If you implement this method I would also return NO:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}
```

You really shouldn't need to be overriding these methods either:

```
hitTest:withEvent:
pointInside:withEvent:
```

If you are, question why, and remove them.

Comment: i did everything you mentioned here but this is still the same

Comment: @or azran Place the code for the UITableViewCell subclass in the question.

Comment: Something that you are doing in the `setSelected:` method is interfering with the usual behaviour.